# create 404 page and add header & footer from my site

Tags: php, html, opencart

I created 404 page to my website but i want to add my header and footer from site [like this site](https://www.bpazar.com/test10) and my site [here](https://noontekmarket.com/)

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What have you already tried yourself to do this? Please review [How much research effort is expected?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users). Stack Overflow is not a coding service. You are expected to research your issue and make a good attempt to write the code yourself before posting. If you get stuck on something specific, come back and include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and a summary of what you tried, so we can help.

Answer (score 0):

basically you have a separate file for the header and you want to include it on the 404 page? if you are using laravel framework its best you use @include('name_of_header_file') if not you should be able to include it directly from the file before the the content like

Comment: thanks jeric, i use opencart and added 404 page from filezilla